# Can I use Stepdefinitions from a another folder which is not under my current folder hierarchy?

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

I want to use existing `step_definitions` from my project in to another set of cucumber ruby tests.

```
Eg: 
|
|- common
|   |- step_difinitions
|   |- feature_file.feature
|
|- Some_other_folder
|   |- someother_feature.feature
|   |- ***Want to reuse the step_difinitions from common folder***
```

Is this at all possible? If not is there any work around for this?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to if your parent folder is `features`. What the parent folder for `common` and `some_other_folder`?

Comment: Yes my parent folder is feature:

```
feature
|
|- common
|   |- step_difinitions
|   |- feature_file.feature
|
|- Some_other_folder
|   |- someother_feature.feature
|   |- ***Want to reuse the step_difinitions from common folder***
```

Comment: So you should be able to use the step defs across the folders from your .feature files. Are you getting any error message when try to use the step def from common folder?

Comment: I am getting ```Undefined step: "stepname" (Cucumber::Undefined) Error

Comment: Have you tried calling the common step_def in the other step_def implementation? Something like this `step 'common method step goes here'`?

Comment: Yes. I have used the common steps somewhere in my features which are places in ```common``` folder. Now I want to create a different folder inside ```feature``` folder. I just tried moving my feature file in new folder but it does not go out of my new folder to search for the step def's

Comment: Try to move both folder `common` and `other folder with step defs into `step_definitions` folder and see. Generally we will keep all .features under `features > whateverFolder` and .rb step def files under `features > step_definitions` folder.

Comment: I need to have different folders for different tasks and each have feature files. I tried moving all step definitions in to a single folder under feature->step_def. I think cucumber only tries to find step_def folder within the folder where *.feature files is placed and it will not go one step higher in hierarchy to find it!!!!

Comment: What's your `Runner Options:`? it should be something like this `--color -r features`. Where `features` is the folder which holds the parent folder with all features and step def.

Comment: I am using ```rake['feature_file_name'] require=features products=product_name``` . 

I have following folders in ```features folder```:
common, product1, product2, product3 - each of them have feature files only

Also, I have a common step definitions folder in ```features``` folder: ```step_definitions```

it did throw errors with undefined scenarios.!!!

Comment: I had a wrapper around the cucumber commands. I made a change to the wrapper to use ```-r path_to_step_def's``` and it works perfect! Thanks for you help @supputuri !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the step definitions are under `features` folder (any where in sub-folder is also fine). Then you have to use the below command to pick-up the step-defs as part of your features execution.

> -r features_folder_path_goes_here

If you are using the rubymine then you can go to `Run > Edit Configuration` and enter the `Runner Options : --color -r feature_folder_path_goes_here` or simply you can specify `--color -r features`.

[image]

FYI - `--color` nothing to do with this issue, it will make sure the output shows in color.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my `step_defs` out of common feature files folder in to the `features` folder and used

`-r features/step_definitions` while running the cucumber CLI command.

I had a wrapper around the cucumber commands. So make sure you use `-r path` in the cucumber commands.

Thanks to @supputuri for help!